# ERROR: useradd: useradd command did not succeed in Yocto build

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to create a user and add it to the dialout group.

I have made a recipe that inherits useradd and adds the users my system needs.

Here is the relevant part of my recipe:

```
inherit useradd                                                                                     

USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"                                                                          

USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "-d /home/myuser -r -m -s /bin/bash myuser -g 
mygroup -G dialout;"                                                                               

GROUPADD_PARAM_${PN} = "-g 870 mygroup;"
```

The build gets to the rootfs_build step before getting an error. The log shows:

```
NOTE: useradd: Performing useradd with [--root 
/mnt/hdd1/yocto/build/tmp/work/intel_corei7_64-poky- 
linux/core-image-sato/1.0-r0/rootfs -d /home/myuser -r -m -s /bin/bash 
myuser -g mygroup -G dialout]                                                                                         
ERROR: useradd: useradd command did not succeed
```

Without the `-G dialout` option it works flawlessly.
Any idea on how to solve this?
I have also tried inheriting extrausers and doing `usermod -aG dialout myuser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved it in the end was to split up each useradd in its own recipe. I have no idea why it didn't work to have them in the same recipe, as that is based on [this](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-skeleton/recipes-skeleton/useradd/useradd-example.bb) example in meta-skeleton.

So instead of having one users.bb with several users, I now have user1.bb, user2.bb etc., and it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is due to the fact that the `dialout` group does not exist, at least not at the time when `myuser` is being added.

If you skip the `-G dialout` part and build an image, do you have a group called dialout in `/etc/group`? If not, you can create the `dialout` group in the same way you create `mygroup`. If it already exists I suspect you will need to make sure the package adding the `dialout` group is installed before your package using something like `RDEPENDS_${PN} += "<package that provides dialout group>`.

Comment: That sounded plausible to me, but what solved it was to split up each useradd in its own recipe. Not a very satisfying solution. More details in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. The solution was to use `:` instead of `_` when `${PN}` was appended:

```
inherit useradd                                                                                     

USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"  
                                                                        
USERADD_PARAM:${PN} = "-d /home/myuser -r -m -s /bin/bash myuser -g mygroup -G dialout;"                                                                               

GROUPADD_PARAM:${PN} = "-g 870 mygroup;"
```

I believe this is due to the new override syntax. In other cases, `bitbake` complains (I use "honister"), for example:

```
do_install_append() {
    ...
}
```

results this error message:
`Variable do_install_append contains an operation using the old override syntax. Please convert this layer/metadata before attempting to use with a newer bitbake.`

This can be resolved by using `do_install:append()`.

Here is the full reference of the override syntax:
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual-metadata.html#conditional-syntax-overrides